# How do i get a object from pouchdb without promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, pouchdb

I'm using jquery datatables and for one of my columns, I'm changing the value the user sees based on the default data. Example

```
...,
columns: [
  { "title": 'Category', render: function ( data, type, row ) {return db.categoryName(data);}}
],
...
```

Then in my function I get pouchdb object by id and return the found object name

```
  categoryName(id) {
    return dbQuery.doc(id).then((arg) => {
      console.log("the category name", arg.name);
      return arg.name;
    });
  }
```

I get the correct output to the console but the view shows `[object Promise]` for every document. I'm having a very hard time with promises when i just want to return a value the way i would without promises.

How can i just return a value from the promise so that I can use my categoryName function? Or is there another way to get a value from pouchdb without using promises so I can have my categoryName function return a value instead of a promise object?

Answer (score 1):

The fetch operation is asynchronous which is why you can only return a promise.

The only other option you have is to pass a callback:

```
categoryName(id, cb) {
  dbQuery.doc(id).then((arg) => {
    console.log("the category name", arg.name);
    cb(arg.name);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [PouchDB API docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html) say:

> PouchDB has an asynchronous API

So **it's not possible to return the value right away since it's not available immediately**, however, you can ask to be notified when the value is ready by passing a callback to the method

```
function categoryNameWithCallback(id, cb) {
  // TODO: handle error
  // Note that this method returns undefined
  db.doc(id, (err, doc) => cb(doc.name))
}
```

Or by using promises

```
function categoryName(id) {
  return db.doc(id).then(doc => doc.name)
}
```

You should read the awesome design notes for [kriskowals/q promise library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/v1/design) to understand a little bit of the drawbacks of getting notified by simple callbacks as opposed to using promises

---

Now back to your problem, you could refactor your code as follows

```
function render(name) {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    columns: [
     { "title": 'Category', render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        // `name` will be available after the promise is resolved but not immediately
        if (name) return name
        // perform the async operation now and rerender the table when the value is available
        categoryName(data).then(render)
        // render with the default value first
        return data;
     }}
    ]
  })
}

render()
```